# Angle between looking direction and latitude/longitude

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I am experimenting a little with AR. I have got the angle of the direction I am looking to from a compass in degrees. I know my own position and the position of another object (POI), the position is giving in form of latitude and longitude.

Now I would like to know how I can calculate the angle between the direction I am looking to and the POI.

Answer (score 0):

Dot Product:

```
a . b = ||a|| ||b|| cos(t)
t = acos( (a.b)/(||a|| ||b||) )


||vector|| = length of vector (magnitude)
t          = angle between the two vectors
```

Your probably going to need to do this a couple times for each plane you have. (1x for 2D, 2x for 3D)

Or:

```
    /|
   / |
h /  | y
 /   |
/____|
  x
```

t is the lower left corner, which we'll assume is your object, the upper right corner is going to be your other object

```
x = obj2.x - obj1.x
y = obj2.y - obj1.y
h = sqrt( (x*x) + (y*y) )

sin(t) = y/h
cos(t) = x/h
tan(t) = y/x

t = asin(y/h)
t = acos(x/h)
t = atan(y/x)
```

What makes the first method better, is that it account's for you're current rotation. The second method (using atan, asin, and acos) doesn't.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I thought of this myself, but can I just assume that latitude = x and longitude = y ? Or do I understand this wrong? And where does the heading of the compass come in?
Or should I just create a new lat/long point from my destination with help of the compass heading? Could I in this case assume that bearing = compass heading? Sry if I didnt understand you but I am really new to AR, compass, lat/long and this kind of stuff ;)

Comment: @user1990524 The lat/long coordinate system is not quite rectangular, but if you assume it to be rectangular as this answer suggests, the difference will be much smaller than you can measure with a handheld compass.  However, the heading you calculate will be relative to true north, not  to magnetic north like your compass.  To get the proper compass heading, you will need to covert using the [magnetic declination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination) for the area you are in.  A [declination calculator](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/#declination) may help.

Comment: I use the compass in the iphone. And you can get true heading(I guess it means geographic north)So it is no need to use magnetic declination